# How to use xlwings to run a macro from one excel onto another excel?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I searched on google and find out how to excute a macro by xlwings in python. However, now I have two excels, A with a macro but no data, B with data but no macro. Then how to excute the macro in A onto B? You can understand that I wanna write a macro script and then use it to process many excels in python. How should I do?

Thanks!

All information have been above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want execute macro, but get data from many files, then you must in VBA use **Workbooks** object. Its possible in different way:

```
Workbooks("B.xlsx").Worksheets("test3").Range("A1", "D5").Value = Null
```

and you can use

```
Windows("B.xlsx").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("test5").Range("C4").Select
```

More about this in excel manual https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook
or more easy text https://trumpexcel.com/vba-workbook/